# Creating many lines from point feature using ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, points-to-line, error-000972

I would like to create many line from a point feature, or a table (I created the feature with 'Display XY Data'). I was using 'points to line', but it works only for a single line. In the point feature I have a field where is described for each point to which line it correspont. But if I put this lineID in the 'Line_Field', it says me:

> ERROR 000972: Table must have Object IDs in order to be sorted.

but the table has the ObjectID, and if I let the 'Line_Field' empty it works but than I have only a line.

Comment: Although you have an ObjectID field it's not an *OID* field.. it's not enough for it to just be there it has to be recognized as an OID which CSV files don't support. Import the CSV into a geodatabase table and an OID field will be created then you should be able to sort the table.

Comment: Ty, now it works, but then I don't understand why to connect all the points with a line it works without ObjectID and for many lines it need it.